# bash: how to replace only one field if two lines have the same content in that field

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Ok this is making me go crazy.

I have a colon separated 4 fields file. I am trying to only replace the last field with a variable. but the problem is when two lines have the same content then both of them will get changed. I was thinking if I can give sed a reference on which line I want to change. In another words, if the first field is R2 then replace its last field

file:

```
R1:name1:date1:black
R2:name2:date2:black
```

I want it to be like this

```
R1:name1:date1:black
R2:name2:date2:black2
```

Here is what I have so far

variable has already been assigned the forth field. name has been assigned the zenity text box for the user to enter the name.

```
variable=$(awk -F ":" '$2 ~ /'"$name"'/ {print $4}' file)

sed -i 's/'$variable'/black2/g' file
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should it not change both lines?

Comment: You have `/g` (Global replacement) in your sed. It replaces all the values sed finds. Well, without `g`, only the first match will be replaced. Is that ok?

Comment: because it is not suppose to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work because without g it will again replace both

Comment: It will be 100x easier for the S.O. users if  you modify your post to include a sample of the output that you need. Your title says 'replace only one field if two lines have the same content in that field'. So given your example data, only the last line should be changed? That *may* be possible with sed, but not easy. Using awk or perl will make it relatively easy. Please add a tag for a programming language (besides bash) if you can use that solution. Good luck.

Comment: It could be the last line or the first line. I was thinking to give a reference of the first field, I mean if the first field is R2 then replace its last field

Comment: Then why not add `R2:` in your `awk` regex? Like `variable=$(awk -F "R2:" '$2 ~ /'"$name"'/ {print $4}' file)`

Comment: why are you putting R2: in the field separator?, the result will be nothing because R2: is not the field separator, the field separator is colon.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit which lines sed applies its substitution to with:

```
sed -i '/^R2/s/:black$/:black2/' file
```

Notice the `^`for the beginning of the line, and the `$`to avoid replacing black somewhere else in the line.

**Edit**:  I removed the g argument to sed as a single substitution is needed per line.  The g argument applies to lines, not to the overall input.

Answer (score 2):

Or a solution with awk, but without being possible to modify the file *in place* like sed, so a mv is needed:

```
awk -F ":" '($1 == "R2" && $4 == "black"){print $1 ":" $2 ":" $3 ":black2"} ($1 != "R2" || $4 != "black"){print $1 ":" $2 ":" $3 ":" $4}' file > file1
mv file1 file
```

or maybe shorter:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1 ":" $2 ":" $3 ($1 == "R2" && $4 == "black"? ":black2" : ":" $4)}' file > file1
mv file1 file
```

Comment: I studied these awk commands also but the last one (sed) is more understandable and easy to follow, but anyway Thank you for your effort on providing the second and third option.